# How prevent my phone from hiding the country code?

Tags: caller-id

My Samsung s8+ called id only shows the local phone number without country code. (023455678 instead of +123455678)

How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you getting the same format even for a international call or just for local ones?

Comment: @parthu_panther only for local calls

Comment: its because of your sim is registered with same locality. If both the sender and receiver are from same country than there's no need of showing country code.

Answer (score 0):

[source](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-all-mobile-phone-numbers-start-with-0) Go through this link for more understanding.

**Conclusion:**

- A leading 0 or "(0)" is a way of showing that you have provided the full phone number in the national format.  The 0 represents the national dialing prefix; the caller will know to omit the leading 0 if they are placing a local call.
- A leading + is a way of showing that you have provided the full phone number in international E.164 format.  The "+" will tell the caller that they need to dial the international dialing prefix such as "00" or "011" if they are calling from outside the country; and that conversely they may need to dial a "0" or "1" if calling from within the country.

Comment: It was not the case for my all past sim cards and handset and it introduce problems form me.  This is related to the sim not the handset, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes its all about carrier operators rules and terms. There's nothing to worry about.

Comment: you can accept the answer if you found it useful.